# How to clear UserDefault for a specific key after 12 hours

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I'm trying to remove a user default key by setting up a Timer after user login.After research and try, i found that timer will not run when app enter background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store a `loginDate` in user default, and do a check with `Date().timeIntervalSince(loginDate) > 12 * 60 * 60` in `applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)`

Comment: You need to combine this with a timer.

Comment: Thanks! You save my time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some task in background, you have to enable background mode for the app. But that will allow only some minutes to run app in background.

Rather than that, you should save time stamp of login time and check on every `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` about time difference of current time and time you saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use **DispatchQueue.global** instead of **NSTimer** , set global queue to background. And in execution use DispatchWorkItem.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + TimeInterval(yourtime interval value), execute: workItem)

var workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
// write your flush userdefault code here
}
```

After using workItem cancel it.

```
self.workItem?.cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
// Write your code here timer running while app will not turminate
}
```